# Material dialog is not displaying buttons corectlly

Tags: android, material-ui, dialog

When app displays dialog with long text via MaterialAlertDialogBuilder buttons are cropped on some devices.

my code:

```
            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.placeholder))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .show()
```

How do I make them displayed properly?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vncDK.png)
[Screenshot from another device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDCGw.png)

Comment: Are those examples an indication of real use? I mean the length of the message. Dialogs aren't necessarily used for long texts like this. If you want the message to be scrollable I think you will need custom layout for that.

Comment: I wanted to use dialog as an info tab for some actions. I also thought about using custom layout but I was wondering if that messages that long can be scrolled without it. Thanks for clearing this up for me

Comment: @Czapla if the button on the bottom is cut when you scroll at the bottom of the list probably it means that something else is pushing the content, I would take a guess it has something to do with the header. I would suggest to inspect the dialog window and you should be able to identify the cause of the issue as you will probably have the same problem even if you add a scrollable area. If you are still stuck, please create a codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a solution - it happened to be caused by `windowTranslucentStatus` in my theme file, thanks to this i was able to continue using dialog with `setMessage` method for long messages.

Comment: so what is the solution here? Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

As TheLibrarian mentioned, for longer texts you'll need to include a scrollable custom layout. But you can still use an AlertDialog.Builder and just call setView() with your scrollable TextView layout:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/dialogs#CustomLayout